# Idiom for creating a result set with a column for each of a fixed set of values belonging to one column?

Tags: sql, database-schema

Verbose title, but hopefully easy to demonstrate with an example. Say I have a table like:

```
    CREATE TABLE sweaters (colour TEXT, size INTEGER, stock INTEGER);
```

the data looks like:

```
red 4   100
red 6   100
red 8   200
black   2   200
black   4   150
black   6   300
```

For each size, I want to know how many red sweaters we have in stock, and how many black. And I want the output to look like this:

```
size    n_red   n_black
2   0   200
4   100 150
6   100 300
```

I could do it like this:

```
SELECT size, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN colour='red' THEN stock ELSE 0 END) as n_red,
    SUM(CASE WHEN colour='black' THEN stock ELSE 0 END) as n_black
FROM sweaters GROUP BY size;
```

But this feels inelegant, and I find myself needing to do it a lot. Is there a better idiom?

Edit: I should mention, SQLite is the engine I'm using.

Comment: you want to pivot over color?

Comment: You could use joins, or unions, but in my opinion this is the more elegant method. There might be other ways specific to some particular database (like `pivot` or `filter`).